# I need to display the year and the value it lost in that particular year

Tags: basic

I am in need of your assistance with my visual basic code. I need to display the double depreciation of a product. Each year the product will lose value. I need to display the year and the value it lost in that particular year using Visual Basic

I have the Interface the code but when I run the code I get incorrect output.
For example:
Product cost is R 5000
Useful Life is 5 Years
when I apply the formula to the problem the answer should be:
1 should be 2000
2 should be 1200
3 should be 720
4 should be 432
5 should be 259.20

With my code I do get year 1 correct but years 2 - 5 have the same answer as year 1.

I have used a for loop to do the calculations but it seems to be stuck at year 1.

Any assistance will be appreciated as I am completely new to programming.

```
Calculating the Depreciation
Sub Calculations()
For yr As Integer = 1 To Life
If yr <= Life Then
Depreciation = (2 / Life) * Cost
lstBalances.Items.Add(yr & " " & Depreciation)
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not adjusting the cost for the next calculation.  Also your line `If yr <= Life Then` is redundant.  The scope of the loop is already defined in the For/Next context and yr will always be less than or equal to Life.

```
Sub Calculations()
   For yr As Integer = 1 To Life
      Depreciation = (2 / Life) * Cost
      lstBalances.Items.Add(yr & " " & Depreciation)
      Cost = Cost - Depreciation
   Next
End Sub
```